# Is there a way to make retrofit/gson cast a double timestamp to long?

Tags: java, json, casting, gson, retrofit2

I'm developing an `Android` app. I'm using retrofit with `Gson` to make calls to the server and serialize/deserialize. In a request, there is a response class which contains a `timestamp` (`long`). Sometimes it is a `double` since the `iOS` version of the app uses `double` to store timestamps.

Is there a way to force `Gson` to deserialize the response and cast to the object present on the `Response` class(long)?

Exception:

```
Caused by com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Expected a long but was 1555323142345.364 at line 1 column 1002 path $.userSettings.stories[4].readTimestamp
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11.read(TypeAdapters.java:323)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11.read(TypeAdapters.java:313)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
       at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
       at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
       at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:119)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:218)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)
       at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall.execute(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:91)
       at inesc_id.pt.motivandroid.motviAPIClient.MotivAPIClientManager$CheckOnboardingNeededAndRetrieve.doInBackground(MotivAPIClientManager.java:909)
       at inesc_id.pt.motivandroid.motviAPIClient.MotivAPIClientManager$CheckOnboardingNeededAndRetrieve.doInBackground(MotivAPIClientManager.java:711)
       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:307)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Class:

```
public class StoryStateful implements Serializable{

    @Expose
    int storyID;

    @Expose
    boolean read;

    @Expose
    long readTimestamp;

    @Expose
    long availableTimestamp;
}
```

Comment: try using float

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Replace long with float type

Comment: You can write a custom de-serializer for the object. Refer - https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For simplicity assume that your `JSON` payload is:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1555323142345.345
}
```

And it should fit to:

```
class Pojo {

    private long timestamp;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Solution depends whether you can change `Pojo` model or not. In case yes and you want to store `double` and `long` it is possible to change type to `Number`:

```
private Number timestamp;
```

And you should be able to parse `double`'s and `long`'s timestamps. In case you always want to have `long` you need to implement custom deserialiser:

```
class LongOrDoubleJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Long> {

    @Override
    public Long deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json.isJsonPrimitive()) {
            Number number = json.getAsNumber();

            return number.longValue();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

And your `Pojo` property should look like:

```
@JsonAdapter(LongOrDoubleJsonDeserializer.class)
private long timestamp;
```

If you can not change `Pojo` class you need to implement custom `TypeAdapterFactory` and register using `GsonBuilder`. See this link: [Creating the Retrofit instance](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit#creating-the-retrofit-instance). Custom implementation could look like:

```
class LongOrDoubleTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        Class<? super T> rawType = type.getRawType();
        if (rawType == Long.class || rawType == long.class) {
            return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
                @Override
                public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) {
                }

                @Override
                public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                    try {
                        return (T) new Long(in.nextLong());
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        return (T) new Long(((Double) in.nextDouble()).longValue());
                    }
                }
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And register as below:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(new LongOrDoubleTypeAdapterFactory())
    .create();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michal! I will try to implement your solution and report back

Comment: I cannot change the pojo. I'm trying to apply the second way. Can I register a TypeAdapterFactory for a specific class? I don't want to apply this logic to all double values, just those inside a specific class.

Comment: @Poider12, I understand but new adapter factory tries to deserialise values as `double` only if parsing as `long` failed. So, it should be safe to use. If you do not want to use it you can always implement custom deserialise for wrapper object (`stories` in your case) and register it by `registerTypeAdapter` method.

Comment: @Poider12, did my answer was helpful? If yes, you can upvote and accept. See: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help Michal! We ended using an approach to correct this issue server side. Due to your answer I´ve able to learn a lot more how deserialization and serialization work!